# Failure to open database file Android NDK (Cocos2d-x)

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm having trouble opening a sqlite3 file by passing the directory of it to sqlite3_open().

By logging the result, and the value of dbPath, it can be seen that sqlite does attempt to, and the file has been found. What I'm unsure about is if the format of dbPath is correct.

The following code returns false, as result != SQLITE_OK, it equals SQLITE_CANTOPEN instead.

```
//load from the Data/ directory (or assets/ if android)
std::string dbPath = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("molemioDB.sql");

result = sqlite3_open(dbPath.c_str(),&pDB);

//failed to open database?
if (result != SQLITE_OK){
    CCLOG("ERROR: Failed to open database: %i", result);

    return false;
}
```

Result has a value of 14, and from sqlite3.h:

```
#define SQLITE_CANTOPEN    14   /* Unable to open the database file */
```

And dbPath's value is shown after using a MessageBox to display it. It equals:

```
"assets/molemioDB.sql"
```

Why does this happen? The database file is inside the assets file in proj.android. And, also in the Data/ folder in the highest directory on my computer - although this is for the iOS version, which loads the database perfectly fine.

A few things to note is that the database is obviously precreated, using a python script I had written. The permissions for the molemioDB.sql file is 644, although the database is only read.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try writing molemioDB.db3 instead of molemioDB.sql

Comment: @Sumit Unfortunately, that didn't work. Even when creating a file called molemioDB.db3, and placing it in the Resources/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android assets cannot be accessed directly, neither in Java nor in native code. They **are not files** on the filesystem but are compressed data inside of your APK.

Here's what you should do:

1. Android has built-in support for SQLite. Rather than including a database file in your app, **let your app create the database** in Java, using what's provided in the [android.database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) package. This will create a regular SQLite database file (usually found in `data/data/your.app.package/databases/`) accessible in native code.
2. If that's not feasible and you really want to go with the asset approach, use [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) in Java to **extract** the asset and create a regular file accessible in native code, i.e. effectively creating a copy of what's contained in the asset.

Perhaps the best thing in the long run would be to restructure your app such that you do not need to handle a database in native code at all. Instead, open and query the database in Java (using one of the two solutions above) and pass **only the necessary data** to native code. Typically, the more application logic you can shift to Java, the better.

Comment: The purpose of the database is just a wordlist. It provides a very fast lookup, in order to check whether the word exists. No writing to the file. Can I store this in res/raw somehow?
I don't feel copying a 5MB database file using the app would be a pleasant experience, plus, it uses 5MB of extra data. And, as the wordlist contains about 260000 entries, it's not a very good idea to _create_ a database on launch of the app.

How could I store this data then, being able to quickly access it?

Comment: I am not aware of any feasible solution via storing it in res/raw. But why would it be a bad idea to create the database dynamically? Mind that it would only have to happen at the *first* launch of the app, and you could rather easily delegate the work to a background thread to keep the UI responsive (using `AsyncTask` et al).

Comment: I've used android to read a text file from res/raw before, but that was pretty slow to add to an array. It took about 40-50 seconds. And this is on a 1.2GHz phone. I don't even believe the tutorial for the game would take that long. Not a very good UX for the first runtime - might even prompt people to delete!

**EDIT**: I've found this site, and the time factor doesn't seem to be to bad. About 9 times better than reading and copying!
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
(it's in java, so I could implement using the jni?)

Comment: It's hard to say what caused the performance hit when you read the text file. Perhaps parsing the input and populating a huge array in memory was what caused it, not so much the sheer file I/O. Have you tried hard-coding the SQL CREATE TABLE statements in your Java code? As for that site, isn't it just suggestion 2 from my answer?

Comment: Well, it was just a line by line insert, so I doubt much parsing.

I remember trying to hardcode in the ~260k array references, and it froze Eclipse after loading it (corrupting the project), due to the sheer LOC. However, as I'm not using an IDE any more, it shouldn't be an issue anymore.

And yes, that site is an implementation of the second point, however it was the comments that interested me, as they mentioned the performance increases compared to simple iteration over every element, and then copying.

Thanks for this though, you've been an extreme help. Thanks for your time so far!